# What's the `name` in `export default`?

Tags: ecmascript-6, vue.js

I am looking a vue project, a `Users.vue`, in its `<script>`, the `export default` have `name: 'users'`:

```
<template>

</template>

<script>

  export default{
    name:'users',  // there is a `name: 'users'` key-value.
    data(){
      return {
        users:[
          {name:'Henry', position:'Web developer', show:false},
          {name:'Henry', position:'Web developer', show:false},
          {name:'Henry', position:'Web developer', show:false},
          {name:'Henry', position:'Web developer', show:false},
          {name:'Henry', position:'Web developer', show:false},
          {name:'Henry', position:'Web developer', show:false},
          {name:'Henry', position:'Web developer', show:false},
          {name:'Henry', position:'Web developer', show:false}
        ]
      }
    },
    components: {}
  }
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

I want to know what is the `name: 'users'` function in there. In previous, I see other project, there is no `name: users` in there.

---

**EDIT-1**

I mean in the `Users.vue`, whether the `name: users` is related to the `Users.vue`? or it just a element in `export default`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [doc](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#name):

> Allow the component to recursively invoke itself in its template. Note that when a component is registered globally with Vue.component(), the global ID is automatically set as its name.
>
> Another benefit of specifying a name option is debugging. Named components result in more helpful warning messages. Also, when inspecting an app in the vue-devtools, unnamed components will show up as , which isn’t very informative. By providing the name option, you will get a much more informative component tree.

It only works in components. that specifying a name option when debugging, it has helpful warning messages.

Answer (score 0):

The two names are not really related, but it is considered a good practice to use kebab case in the name-property (`name: user-profile`) and name the .vue-file accordingly in pascal case (`UserProfile.vue`).